# sklearn use f_classif and select features with a score higher than threshold

Tags: scikit-learn, feature-selection

I use `f_classif` to determine scores of my features:

```
def select_feature_anova(x,y,data):

    anova = feature_selection.f_classif(x, y)

    threshold = 10

    # How to build x_new?
```

What is the easiest way to transform `x` to `x_new` so that it only includes features with a score higher than threshold? Also I would like to exclude features with a score of `Nan`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [`documentation`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif.html#sklearn.feature_selection.f_classif), we can filter the features based on the F-score.

Try this!

```py
from sklearn.feature_selection import f_classif
import numpy as np
np.seterr(divide='ignore', invalid='ignore')

def select_feature_anova(X, y, threshold=10):

    F,_ = feature_selection.f_classif(X, y)

    X_new = X[:,F>threshold]

    return X_new
```